# Relevance & Exogeneity of IV

Tags: regression, econometrics, linear, instrumental-variables

I got two questions which are somehow closely related:

Let's take the famous study of Acemoglu et al. (The Colonial Origins of Comparative Development: An Empirical Investigation) as an example.

When replicating you will discover, that in the first stage (i.e. regressing the endogenous variable, which in the study is a measure for strength of institution on the excluded instrument which is the settlers mortality) we get an F-statistic of around 10 for the excluded instrument. So if you go by the rule of thumb, we consider that as a borderline case where it is not entirely clear whether mortality of settlers is a weak instrument.

However, we should include all exogenous regressors (such as dummy variables for continents and distance to equator) in the first stage. Doing that will reduce the F-statistic of the excluded instrument down to around 3. In other words we suspect the instrument to be weak, which would lead in the second stage to unstable results.

Now my question: Is there an intuition behind the decrease of the F-statistic? Does that tell us that there is some sort of correlation between the exogenous variables and the excluded instrument, which makes the latter irrelevant? But even so, that fact would tell us absolutely nothing about the exogeneity of the instrument, right?

My second question: Should we not worry about other omitted variables in the first stage, which could potentially even more decrease the relevance of the instrument? In the literature I know, this seems never to be the topic, we just include the exogenous regressors and that's it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, the point of the first stage is to demonstrate that the instrumental variable (IV) is indeed strongly correlated with the endogenous variable we are instrumenting for. If the F-statistic decreases substantially when adding covariates, it intuitively implies that variation in the IV does not account for as much variation in the endogenous variable as previously suggested when relevant covariates were omitted. Thus, the IV may be weak.

It seems the answer to your second question is yes. While generally we do not know if a relevant variable is excluded, the presence of heteroskedasticity and/or autocorrelation can be indicative of an omitted variable. Thus, there has been proposed an effective F-statistic (Olea and Pflueger 2013) that is robust to these misspecifications. The authors propose a new rule of thumb for a strong IV to report an effective F-stat greater than 23.1.

There is a good Annual Review of Economics piece on this that you may be interested in (Andrews et al. 2019). For political science, which is my field, there are also some discussions of this that may interest you (Lal et al. Forthcoming).

You mentioned implications for the exogeneity of the instrument given the first stage. I would not think that omitted variables or a decreasing F-stat in covariates implies an endogenous IV. That is dealt with by the ever-elusive exclusion restriction (validity), where the IV is claimed to be unrelated to the dependent variable except through the endogenous independent variable. An IV can still be valid even if not relevant, but severe bias can be induced if the IV is both weak and invalid, if even slightly. This is in addition to other problems incurred by a weak instrument.

Andrews, Isaiah, James Stock, and Liyang Sun. 2019. "Weak Instruments in Instrumental Variables Regression: Theory and Practice." Annual Review of Economics. https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-economics-080218-025643

Lal, Apoorva, Mac Lockhart, Yiqing Xu and Ziwen Zu. Forthcoming (Political Analysis). "How Much Should We Trust Instrumental Variable Estimates in Political Science? Practical Advice Based on Over 60 Replicated Studies." https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.11399

Olea, José Luis Montiel and Carolin Pflueger. 2013. "A Robust Test for Weak Instruments." Journal of Business and Economic Statistics. https://www.jstor.org/stable/43702731?seq=1